# PHP Composer "no matching package found" (Mozu PHP API)

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I am trying to get up and running with the Mozu PHP API which relies on Composer for required libraries. Composer keeps failing requirement tests as follows:

Composer file:

```
cat composer.json
{
        "name" : "mozu/api",
        "description" : "SDK for Mozu Rest APIs",
        "type" : "library",
        "homepage" : "https://developer.mozu.com/sdks",
        "keywords" : [
                "Mozu",
                "API",
                "SDK"
        ],
        "license" : "MIT",
        "require" : {
                "guzzle/guzzle" : ">=3.7.3@stable",
                "php" : ">=5.4"
        },
        "require-dev" : {
                "phpunit/phpunit" : ">=3.7.28@stable"
        },
        "autoload" : {
                "psr-0" : {
                        "Mozu" : "src/"
                }
        },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.7.x-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Install error:

```
php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package php could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package php could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 3
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.9.2 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.9.1 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.9.0 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.8.1 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.8.0 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.7.4 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.7.3 requires php >=5.3.2 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for guzzle/guzzle >=3.7.3@stable -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2].
```

PHP Version:

```
php -v
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.13 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jul  7 2014 18:52:09)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

PHP Curl Version:

```
apt-get install php5-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php5-curl is already the newest version.
```

Composer version:

```
 php composer.phar self-update
You are already using composer version 1e27ff5e22df81e3cd0cd36e5fdd4a3c5a031f4a.
```

Comment: It may, or may not help for this question, but I've just found the command: `php composer.phar show --platform`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok changed requirement of "php" : ">=5.4" to "php" : ">=5.3" and it worked!

Not sure why it had a requirement for a dev version of php but oh well!